# How to tune Garbage Collection in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

i am working on a ruby project. and i used tunemygc gem to get some optimal settings for my app.

```
RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS 220886
RUBY_GC_HEAP_FREE_SLOTS 3378483
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR  1.03
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_MAX_SLOTS   478
RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR 2.0
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT    16777216
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_MAX    30198989
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_GROWTH_FACTOR  1.32
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT 16777216
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_MAX 30198989
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_GROWTH_FACTOR   1.2
```

but i don't know how to config my garbage collection with these settings.

Comment: why do you feel you need to tune GC?

Comment: just wanna try how much it changes the machine performance.

Comment: You may want to buy the book "Ruby Performance Optimization" and checkout the last chapter on "Tuning the garbage collector" if you're really interested in this.  Not to sound condescending but it's a very advanced topic and I wouldn't recommend it to someone new to stack.

Comment: @bkunzi01 thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Set those as environment variables on your server that are available to the ruby process when it starts. As in:

```
export RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS=220886
...
```

Then start your ruby app

Answer (score 0):

If your app is on heroku, you can also use the free heroku add on, and apply all the recommended settings with just one button.